# multirow position not correct, how to fix it?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I have three figures to be put in a way

subfig1

-------subfig3

subfig2

And `height(subfig3)=height(subfig1)+height(subfig2)`, so that the top of subfig3 is aligned with the top of subfig1, and the bottom of subfig3 is aligned with the bottom of subfig2.

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{subfig1.png} &
\multirow{2}{*}{\includegraphics[width=8cm]{subfig3.png}} \\
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{subfig2.png}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

But I found the position of subfig3 is too low, it is not centered. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `multirow` for this: put the images on the left in a `minipage`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{minipage}[b]{4cm}
\offinterlineskip % no vertical space between the two images
\includegraphics[height=3cm,width=4cm]{example-image}\\
\includegraphics[height=5cm,width=4cm]{example-image}
\end{minipage}
\includegraphics[height=8cm,width=4cm]{example-image}

\caption{Three images}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This exploits the fact that the reference point of the images are at their bottom.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

EDITED to use `\shortstack` rather than `\vcenter`.  The command `\shortstack` starts building up from the baseline, so there are no depth-below-baseline issues with which to contend.  However, there is a slight gap between the two left-hand images, which means that the right-hand image won't perfectly align, unless you take care of it by effectively trimming it (as I did below by wrapping the `\includegraphics` inside of an `\addvbuffer`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\shortstack{%
\addvbuffer[-1pt]{\includegraphics[height=3cm,width=4cm]{example-image}}\\
\addvbuffer[-1pt]{\includegraphics[height=5cm,width=4cm]{example-image}}
}
& 
\addvbuffer[-1pt]{\includegraphics[height=8cm,width=4cm]{example-image}}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]